# Jira REST API, JSON to create an Issue of type Test with test detail

Tags: json, rest, api, jira

So far I manage to create the Test issue, but I can't find the correct JSON structure to populate the field:
customfield_11101 , name: Zephyr Teststep , required: false , type: any

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
var issueTest = {
    "fields": {
      "issuetype": {
         "name": "Test"
      },
      "project":
      {
         "key": "STORYKEY"
      },
      "summary": "Navigate to a Different Region",
      "description": "",
      "assignee": {
          "name": "someemail@email.com"
      },
      "customfield_10014": "SOMEKEY",

      "duedate": "2018-10-03",
      "priority": {
        "name": "Blocker"
      },
      "labels": ["label1", "label2"],
      "customfield_19416": "50h",
      "customfield_19719": {
        "value": "minor"
      },
      "customfield_11101": [
        {
          "Test Step": "some text",
          "Test Data": "some text",
          "Test Result": "some text"
        },
        {
          "Test Step": "some text",
          "Test Data": "some text",
          "Test Result": "some text"
        },
        {
          "Test Step": "some text",
          "Test Data": "some text",
          "Test Result": "some text"
        }
      ]
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely familiar with the Zephyr fields but have you tried something like this:

```
"fields": {
  //other field data
  "customfield_11101": {
    "value": //put your array here
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work then find another issue in your JIRA instance that has that field filled out and query it through the API, you can then see what the structure of that field's value should be

Thirdly, if all else fails, Zephyr has their own [API](http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#) which you can probably use to make the changes you need. There's a separate [TeststepResource](http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#reference/teststepresource) endpoint even.

Answer (score 0):

First I want the thanks @rorschach, his answer help me a lot.

I find a way. it is not ideal but works
The idea is create the Test and use the new Test id to create the related steps using this (suggested by @rorschach):

http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#reference/teststepresource/create-get-list-of-teststeps/create-new-teststep